# Rails, pjax and DataTables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables, pjax

I've got a Rails app utilizing pjax (pjax.heroku.com/) so that my header and navbar don't ever reload. It's all fine and dandy and working, BUT in one of my views I'm using a data table (datatables.net). The data table works great when you first load up the page, but if you navigate away to another page and then come back, the table doesn't "reinitiate", so it doesn't work and everything looks like crap. Apparently it's because the data tables js file isn't getting loaded up again due to pjax.

Here's what I've got:

`application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require pjax
//= require_tree .
```

In the head of `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And then wrapped the `<%=` yield `%>` in a div with `data-pjax-container`.

I'm calling the data-tables js file in `index.html.erb` (hard-coded) underneath the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data-table.js"></script>
```

Then in a separate `custom.js` file, this is what initiates the table:

```
$(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]');
$('.openinside').pjax('.sidebarInner');
```

Any idea what's going on here? I think the table isn't being reinitiated, but how can I make it reinitiate when the header isn't getting loaded every time due to Pjax? I tried putting the JS link right beneath the table even and that didn't work!

Comment: Had a similar problem with turbolinks. Find a way to init your table, that should fix the problem.

Comment: @sytycs Yeah that's where I'm stuck. This is probably a stupid question, but should the init script go before or after the call to data-tables.js?

Comment: @sytycs I'm thinking about giving turbolinks a shot anyway. Can you share the solution you used to init the table?

Comment: well its a little tricky. I replaced my `.on` calls with `.live` calls, event though `.live` is deprecated (not recommended). You need to figure out when to call your table init again. I'm no js expert so thats all I have for now. sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps (since this question is from a month ago now), but I'm in a similar boat. I have a pjax datatable that loads in my in my pages coffeescript file.

So I'm calling the load on **pjax:end**, which does work, but I'm now looking for a way to load if it's called normally (so either document complete or on pjax:end).

```
$(document).on "pjax:end", ->
  $("#leads_table").dataTable({bJQueryUI: true, sPaginationType: "full_numbers", bRetrieve: true})
```

Maybe this helps (or helps someone else).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just ditching pjax altogether because it was running slowly and just didn't seem natural as my pages got larger and carried more data. I could very well have been making too many calls or something too. If I go back and try to implement it again, I'll definitely try out your suggestion!